# Реализация функции ajaxsms() для разных версий jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, sms, sendmessage

Не могу понять почему **ajaxsms()** не работает. Консоль: **Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxsms is not defined**. В этот момент 1.11.1/jquery.min.js за комментирован. Ошибок других нет. Только по нажатию кнопки *id="oneClickOrder"*  система не может определить функцию.

Подключена библиотека **jQuery v1.12.4** все функции работают отлично, кроме моей **ajaxsms()**. Если подключаю 1.11.1/jquery.min.js то функция **ajaxsms()** работает на все родные нет. 100% конфликт библиотек.
Что в моем коде не так? Как написать аналог для jQuery v1.12.4 библиотеки?

```
<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
function ajaxsms() {
var msgsms = $("#onesendfinal").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/templates/hera_j3_vm3/send_sms.php",
    data: msgsms,
    success: function (data) { 
$("#ResultQ").html(data); 
},
error: function (data) {  
$("#ResultQ").html(data); 
},
cache: false
});
}
});
</script>
<!--- script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script ---->

<form id="onesendfinal" onsubmit="ajaxsms()" action="javascript:void(0);" name="sendfinal" method="post">
<p class="phone"><b>+38</b>
<input id="checkPhoneCode" type="phone" name="PhoneCode" class="required phone-code" required maxlength="3" value="0" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/[^0-9]/, '')">
<i>&ndash; </i>
<input id="phone-number" type="phone" name="PhoneNumber" class="required phone-number" required maxlength="7" value="" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/[^0-9]/, '')">
</p>
<input id="checkURL" type="hidden" name="hiddenURL" class="required" required value="">
<input type="submit" id="oneClickOrder" class="btn " value="Купить"></form>

<span id="ResultQ"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
window.ajaxcallback = function () {
var msgsms = $("#callbackoneform").serialize();
$.ajax({
type: "post",
url: "/templates/hera_j3_vm3/send_callback.php",
data: msgsms,
success: function (data) { 
$("#ResultCallbackForm").html(data); 
},
error: function (data) {  
$("#ResultCallbackForm").html(data); 
},
cache: false
});
}
});
```

Это решение мне подсказали на форуме, нужно просто объявить функцию г